How to get scheduled and actual flight arrival time from Flightradar24 API?
I'm stuck trying to find the way how to get basic flight information from flightRadar24 API. I need to check actual flight arrival time - it is the first information they are displaying on their website, but not in the api documentation.
I tried to use Flight Track:
try:
`import asyncio
import flightradar24
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil import parser

# Initializing the API client
fr24 = flightradar24.Api()

async def get_flight_status(**kwargs) -> dict[str, object]:
    # Initializing input parameters
    flight_number: str | None = kwargs.get('flight_number', None)
    flight_date: str | None = kwargs.get('flight_date', None)

    # If no date is specified, use the current date
    if not flight_date:
        flight_date = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    else:
        try:
            # Try to parse any date format and convert it to YYYY-MM-DD
            parsed_date = parser.parse(flight_date)
            flight_date = parsed_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
        except ValueError:
            return {"final_answer": f"Invalid date format. Please use a valid date format."}

    # Getting flight information via Flightradar24
    try:
        flight_data = fr24.get_flight(flight_number)
        if flight_data:
            # Check the availability of key time fields
            departure_time = flight_data['time']['scheduled'].get('departure', 'No data')
            arrival_time = flight_data['time']['scheduled'].get('arrival', 'No data')
            status = flight_data.get('status', {}).get('generic', {}).get('status', {}).get('text', 'No status available')

            # Format the result for output
            result = {
                "flight_number": flight_number,
                "departure_time": departure_time,
                "arrival_time": arrival_time,
                "status": status
            }
            return {"result_data": [result]}
        else:
            return {"final_answer": f"No flight data found for {flight_number} on {flight_date}."}
    except Exception as e:
        return {"final_answer": f"Failed to retrieve flight status. Error: {str(e)}"}

# Asynchronous function for execution
async def main():
    flight_info = await get_flight_status(flight_number='EK148')
    print(flight_info)

# Starting the program
if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())`

But it returns error "Failed to retrieve flight status. Error: 'time'"
flight_data = fr24.get_flight(flight_number)
        if flight_data:
            # Check the availability of key time fields
            departure_time = flight_data['time']['scheduled'].get('departure', 'No data')
            arrival_time = flight_data['time']['scheduled'].get('arrival', 'No data')
            status = flight_data.get('status', {}).get('generic', {}).get('status', {}).get('text', 'No status available')

I actually couldn't find flight_data in the API documentetion and asked ChatGPT
